# how to get channel's members telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I used this, `client.iter_participants(channel, aggressive=True)`  but only got 4k users out of 30k
and use

```
while True:
    participants = client(GetParticipantsRequest(
        my_channel, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit,
        hash=0
    ))
    if not participants.users:
        break
    all_participants.extend(participants.users)
    offset += len(participants.users)
```

and the same

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/580

Comment: I used the code from there, it did not work for me

Comment: https://python.gotrained.com/scraping-telegram-group-members-python-telethon/ 
 "set the aggressive parameter to True otherwise you will not get more than 10k"

Comment: but i get only 4k users

Comment: Telegram doesn't want you to fetch that many members. There is simply no way.